# Git clean before or after git reset?

Tags: git

Occasionally I want to change my git working copy to a pristine state.  I do this with the following two commands:

```
git clean -dxf
git reset --hard
```

Is there any reason to run clean before or after reset?  No matter what kind of crazy situation I have got my repo into, could running them in one order or the other ever fail or not get me back to where I want to be, as if I had a clean checkout?

Might I ever need to do something even more complicated like clean-reset-clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason to run clean before or after reset?

Yes. `git clean` responds to the state of the index. `git reset --hard` changes the state of the index. So `git clean` needs to be run after the index state is corrected, which is what `git reset --hard` does.

> Might I ever need to do something even more complicated like clean-reset-clean?

No.

---

Note: This answer is not intended as an endorsement of saying `git clean -dxf`. It merely responds to the specific question on its own terms.